# Can't insert entity Entity framework duplicate key exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have context with Animal entity and Id as Identity column.

This is Animal definition:

```
public class Animal
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There is only one animal in collection:

```
Animals: [{
    Id: 1,
    Name: "Dog"
  }].
```

I want to insert new Animal with following code:

```
context.Animals.Add(new Animal { Name: "Cat" })
```

Following exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type
>   'Animal' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with
>   the same key is already being tracked.

Comment: What line generates the exception - `Add` or `SaveChanges`?

Comment: Seems that EF already tracked `Animal` entity. You need to use already tracked entity to add new data (also provide part of code which throwing exception).

Comment: I guess you are trying to insert same key i.e Id:1

Comment: @IvanStoev Add is generating exception

Comment: And this is happening while executing test, not in normal runtime

Comment: Apparently there is something not shown in the question. [mcve] needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which database do you use? If it is `InMemoryDatabase` from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` and first animal was added with explicit id (by `context.Animals.Add(new Animal { Id: 1, Name: "Cat" })`) then `InMemoryDatabase` does not increment internal identity counter used for id setting. So when you and second animal, `InMemoryDatabase` try to set `Id` to `1` but there is already animal with this `id`, so exception was thrown.

You have two solution:

- Removed explicit id from first animal (I prefer this)
- Explicity set id in second (and all next animals)

Comment: That is exactly what is happening

Comment: So I add two possible solutions

Comment: Third option (strongly recommended): don't use `InMemoryDatabase` but test against an actual database (integration test). You shouldn't change code with the sole purpose to satisfy unit tests.